# Locally unital ideals

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with unity not necessarily commutative and $I$ an ideal of $R$.

Let for every element $a \in I$ there exists an element $c\in I$ such that $ac=a$.
Note that $c$ is related to $a$. Now we have the following question:

> Can we say that  for every element  $a\in I$ there exists an idempotent element $c\in I$ such that $ac=c$?

Off course we have many examples such that the answer is true for them but in general  we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can. $c=c^2=0$ will suffice.

If however your question contains a misprint and you actually meant $ac=a$, as in the assumption, then the answer is "no".

Counterexample: $R=C([0,1])$,
$$
   I=\{f\in C([0,1])\,\colon\, \exists\delta>0\,\text{ such that }f(x)=0,\,x\in[0,\delta]\}.
$$ 
(Of course, $\delta$ depends on $f$.) Note that the assumption holds (exercise: prove this!), but $I$ does not contain nonzero idempotents at all.