# idempotents acting as local identities

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with unity (not necessarily commutative) and $I$ an ideal of $R$.

Suppose that for every element $a \in I$ there exists an element $c\in I$ such that $ac=a$.
Note that $c$ is related to $a$. Now we have the following question:

Can we say that  for every element  $a\in I$ there exists an **idempotent** element $c\in I$ such that $ac=a$?

Of course we have many examples such that the answer is true for them but in general  we don't know.

Comment: "Off course we have many examples such that the answer is true". Well, there are also many examples where the answer is no.

Comment: Do you really want the idempotent to satisfy $ac=c$? If so, what you want is not true in $\mathbb Z$ already (notice that your hypothesis is trivial when $R$ has a unit)

Comment: $ac=a$ and $R$ is a ring with  unity $1_{R}$.

Comment: Correct the question if there is anything to correct.

Comment: You also probably want the idempotent $c$ to be non-zero, for otherwise that $ac=c$ is not very interesting.

Comment: I correct a misprint sorry we want to have  $ac=a$.

Comment: yes it is necessary

Comment: Did you understand? thanks

Comment: I don't know what you meant by «yes it is necessary». In any case, does my answer below not answer your question?

Comment: let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that for every $a\in I$  there exists a $c\in I$ such that $ac=a$. Can we say there exist an idempotent $c\in I$ such that $ac=a$?

Comment: This is the third time this user has tried to post this question: the last time was here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854068/locally-unital-ideals .  I guess now that the user has changed one critical letter the questions are no longer truly identical, and now we have two of them.  @sajad In the future please pay attention to correcting your question and don't repost copies of it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ring $R$ of continuous functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with compact support.

There are no non-zero idempotents in this ring, yet your condition holds. Indeed, if $a\in R$, let $c\in R$ be any function which is equal to $1$ on the support of $a$.

**Later** This ring does not have a unit, and you wwanted it to have one. But if $R$ does have a unit then your question is trivial: you can always take $c=1$!

Comment: We want to hold the condition for every   ideal $I$  of ring $R$ which satisfies assumptions.

Comment: Well, my example works for the ideal $I=R$. Your comment here makes me thing that the quantifiers in your question do not reflect the question you *wanted* to ask. But I will now give up trying to guess what that question was :-|

Comment: For example let $R=\pi_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_P$ and let $I=\oplus  \mathbb{Z}_P$ then $I$ satisfies conditions

Comment: Can you give an example of pure ideal which contains no non-zero idempotent? (this help us to fined the answer).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by «pure». If you meant proper, just take my R above and consider the direct product of R with any ring.

Comment: The ideal $I\subset R$ is pure if and only if $R/I$ is flat   $R$-module.